# Bind variable to literal in Rust pattern matching

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have a state machine written in Rust which needs to perform the same action for two states.

Both states are variants of an enum but contain a different number of elements.

```rust
match self.state {
    RunState::ACCUMULATE(byte, count) | RunState::ESCAPE(count) => todo!(), 
    _ => todo!()
}
```

The example is invalid source code because `byte` is not bound in all patterns.

This could be solved by binding `byte` to a literal zero in the second pattern but i don't know how to archive that.

I`am currently matching both patterns separately which leads to code duplication which i would like to avoid.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Patterns are designed to match by structure and bind variables based on the value being matched. It is not designed to introduce arbitrary bindings. You should use separate `match` arms and perhaps use a helper function if you're concerned about duplication:

```
match self.state {
    RunState::ACCUMULATE(byte, count) => helper(byte, count),
    RunState::ESCAPE(count) => helper(0, count), 
    ...
}
```

Or you can introduce a function for your `enum` that returns the needed values like:

```
impl RunState {
    fn to_parts(&self) -> (u8, usize) { // or Option<(u8, usize)> if its not applicable to all
        match self.state {
            RunState::ACCUMULATE(byte, count) => (byte, count),
            RunState::ESCAPE(count) => (0, count), 
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve your issue by *not* binding `byte` in any branch:

```
match self.state {
    RunState::ACCUMULATE(_, count) | RunState::ESCAPE(count) => todo!(), 
    _ => todo!()
}
```

If you need `byte` in the `ACCUMULATE` case, then the code isn't strictly speaking the same for both, but this can be accomplished with an extra step to extract `byte`:

```
match self.state {
    RunState::ACCUMULATE(_, count) | RunState::ESCAPE(count) => {
        let byte = if let RunState::ACCUMULATE (byte, _) = self.state { byte } else { 0 };
        todo!()
    }, 
    _ => todo!()
}
```